# jdbcTemplate and Oracle 10

Tags: jdbctemplate

Trying to do an insert, I have:
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into....", new Object[]{foo.getId(), foo.getName()})
foo.getId() returns a long, and getName() a String.
I have "NUMBER" as the id type in Oracle, and varchar2 for the name field.

I'm getting SQLtype unknown problem.
the update method has a version where I do not have to put in the SQL types, but do I have to, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the [Spring Framework](http://static.springframework.org) [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) class.  The `JdbcTemplate` methods will attempt to guess the [java.sql.Type](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) for value references, but apparently isn't guessing correctly in this case.

There are a couple of ways to include the type:

The `JdbcTemplate.update(String, Object[])` [javadoc](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])) indicates that you can pass [SqlParameterValue](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlParameterValue.html) instances, consisting of the [java.sql.Type](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) and a *value*.

Alternatively, you can use `JdbcTemplate.update(String, Object[], int[])` passing an array of [java.sql.Type](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)