# Java Types map to Java SQL Types Util

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using the `java.sql.Connection.createArrayOf()` method in order to create an array parameter for my SQL query.

**For example:**

```
Long[] arrayOfLongs = {1L, 2L, 3L};
```

would need to call `conn.createArrayOf("bigint", arrayOfLongs);`

while

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

would need to call

```
conn.createArrayOf("varchar", arrayOfStrings);
```

etc...

**My Question is**: Is there an Utility class out there that maps the Java Types to SQL types (as Strings and not java.sql.TYPES which are ints) ? Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, direct mapping (Java types => SQL types) is not possible since a single Java type can match many SQL types.  You can confirm this with the [Appendix B of the JBDC API Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html).  For instance, a `String` could be mapped to a `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `LONGVARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` or `LONGNVARCHAR`.

Basically, you have to map the Java type to the data type used in the table description of the database.

**Update :**

All JDBC database drivers must implement the [`setObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) setter which seems to be a sort of guessing function for the SQL data type.  Unfortunetely it doesn't seems possible to reuse this function to achieve what you want but you can get a pretty good idea of what it is actually doing by looking at the source code.

Here is a sample of what MySQL is doing to guess the data type :

```
public void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object  parameterObj)
     throws SQLException  {
     if (parameterObj == null) {
         setNull(parameterIndex, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
     } else {
         if (parameterObj instanceof Byte ) {
             setInt(parameterIndex, ((Byte ) parameterObj).intValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof String ) {
             setString(parameterIndex, (String ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof BigDecimal ) {
             setBigDecimal(parameterIndex, (BigDecimal ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Short ) {
             setShort(parameterIndex, ((Short ) parameterObj).shortValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Integer ) {
             setInt(parameterIndex, ((Integer ) parameterObj).intValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Long ) {
             setLong(parameterIndex, ((Long ) parameterObj).longValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Float ) {
             setFloat(parameterIndex, ((Float ) parameterObj).floatValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Double ) {
             setDouble(parameterIndex, ((Double ) parameterObj).doubleValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof byte[]) {
             setBytes(parameterIndex, (byte[]) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Date ) {
             setDate(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Date ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Time ) {
             setTime(parameterIndex, (Time ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Timestamp ) {
             setTimestamp(parameterIndex, (Timestamp ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof Boolean ) {
             setBoolean(parameterIndex,
                 ((Boolean ) parameterObj).booleanValue());
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof InputStream ) {
             setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, (InputStream ) parameterObj, -1);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Blob ) {
             setBlob(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Blob ) parameterObj);
         } else if (parameterObj instanceof java.sql.Clob ) {
             setClob(parameterIndex, (java.sql.Clob ) parameterObj);
         } else {
             setSerializableObject(parameterIndex, parameterObj);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes that's true but if you consider JDBCTEMPLATE for example:
`insert.update("INSERT INTO PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?)",
new Object[] { "MyName", "MyLastName" });`

how does JdbcTemplate know that the Java.lang.String "MyName" maps to a VARCHAR?

Comment: Well it looks like JdbcTemplate is [guessing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.4/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) the data type... and sometimes it makes a [mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300236/jdbctemplate-and-oracle-10).